# How can I change user on gdrive?

Tags: google-drive

Ubuntu version: `14.04.5 LTS`.

> gdrive is a command line utility for interacting with Google Drive.

I have initialized `gdrive` (https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive) with a specific user. As example `gdrive about` returns its information.

The way I install `gdrive`:

```
$ go get github.com/prasmussen/gdrive
$ gopath=$(go env | grep 'GOPATH' | cut -d "=" -f 2 | tr -d '"')
$ echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$gopath/bin' >> ~/.profile
$ source .profile
$ gdrive about # This line authenticates the user only once on the same node.
Authentication needed
Go to the following url in your browser:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=...e=state
Enter verification code:
```

---

```
gdrive about
User: userName userSurname, <e-mail@gmail.com>
Used: 6.5 GB
Free: 9.6 GB
Total: 16.1 GB
Max upload size: 5.2 TB
```

I want to reinitialize/re-authentication `gdrive` again with a completely new user email address.

**[Q]** Is there any way to change the user's information with another email address?

If I remove `gdrive` and re-install it, could it be a solution?

Comment: Please see my updated question @pomsky

Comment: Thanks for updating with more info. Hopefully someone will be able to help you. BTW your [edit suggestion to another related answer](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/823223) is wrong (`grive` should *not* be `gdrive` there) and hence declined. There is no package named `gdrive` [in that PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Enilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8/+index?batch=75&memo=75&start=75), but there are packages named `grive` & `grive2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gdrive help about` will output:

```
Google drive metadata, quota usage
gdrive [global] about [options]

global:
  -c, --config <configDir>         Application path, default: /home/banyhong/.gdrive
  --refresh-token <refreshToken>   Oauth refresh token used to get access token (for advanced users)
  --access-token <accessToken>     Oauth access token, only recommended for short-lived requests because of short lifetime (for advanced users)

options:
  --bytes   Show size in bytes
```

The easiest way to clean authentication data is to `rm -rf ~/.gdrive`.

Comment: `gdrive help about `shows Application path, default: `.gdrive`. Is this normal? @Ping Chu Hung

Comment: In my case, `.gdrive` is under home directory. At which directory did you execute `gdrive help about`? Is `.gdrive` directory also under home directory?

Answer (score 0):

I found an Easiest method to Logout the User Currently login in G-Drive Cli

`rm -rf ~/.gdrive/token_*.json`